Is it possible to reduce the number of loops?
Below is a graph I drew using TikZ, which achieves the purpose. However, I feel that my code is still not concise enough because it uses four for-loops. Is there a more concise method?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    % Define the center point
    \coordinate (u) at (0,0);
    % Draw the vertex u
    \node[draw, circle, fill=blue, inner sep=1pt] (u0) at (u) {$u$};
    % Draw the first circle with radius 1
    %\draw [blue](u) circle (1);
    % Draw the second circle with radius 1.5
    %\draw (u) circle (1.5);
    
    % Draw vertices on the radius 1 circle and connect them to the center
    \foreach \angle/\label in {54/v_0, -18/v_2, -90/v_4, 198/v_6, 126/v_8}
{
    \node[draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=0pt] (w\angle) at ({cos(\angle)}, {sin(\angle)}) {$\label$};
    \draw (u0) -- (w\angle);
}
  

    % Draw vertices on the radius 1.5 circle and connect them to the center
    \foreach  \angle\label in {18/v_1, 90/v_9, 162/v_7, 234/v_5,-54/v_3}
    {
        \node[draw, circle, fill=orange, inner sep=0pt] (w\angle) at ({1.5*cos(\angle)}, {1.5*sin(\angle)}) {$\label$};
        \draw[blue] (u0) -- (w\angle);      
    }

    % Draw vertices on the radius 1.2 circle and connect them to the center
    \foreach \angle [remember=\angle as \lastangle (initially 198)]  in {-90, -18, 54, 126, 198}
    {
     \draw[blue] (w\lastangle) -- (w\angle);
    }

    \foreach \angle [remember=\angle as \lastangle (initially 234)] in {-90, -54, -18, 18, 54, 90, 126,162, 198, 234}
    {
        \draw[thick] (w\lastangle) -- (w\angle);
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Is it possible to reduce the number of loops to make the code more structured?

With two loops and two additional lines:

(you may check if w6 and w8 labels are interchanged ...)
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\node[C=blue!30] (u0)   {$u$};
% orange vertex
\foreach  \angle/\label in {18/v_1, 90/v_9, 162/v_7, 234/v_5,304/v_3}
{
\node[C=orange] (w\angle) at ({1.2*cos(\angle)}, {1.2*sin(\angle)}) {$\label$};
\draw[blue] (u0) -- (w\angle);
}
\draw[very thick] (w18) -- (w90) -- (w162) -- (w234) -- (w304) -- (w18);
% white vertex
\foreach \angle/\label in {54/v_0, -18/v_2, -90/v_4, 126/v_6, 198/v_8}
{
\node[C=white] (w\angle) at ({cos(\angle)}, {sin(\angle)}) {$\label$};
\draw (u0) -- (w\angle);
}
\draw[blue]   (w54) -- (w-18) -- (w-90) -- (w198) -- (w126) -- (w54);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

At least above code is quite sorter than yours :-)
Addendum:
with just one loop and \ifodd macro from TeX:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\node[C=blue!30] (u0)   {$u$};


\foreach  \i  in {0, 1, ..., 9}
{\ifodd\i
    \node[C=orange] (n\i) at (54-\i*36:1.225) {$v_\i$};  
    \draw[red] (u0) -- (n\i);
 \else
    \node[C=white] (n\i) at (54-\i*36:1) {$v_\i$};
    \draw   (u0) -- (n\i);
 \fi
}
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\draw[blue]    (n0) -- (n2) -- (n4) -- (n6) -- (n8) -- (n0);
\draw[thick]   (n1) -- (n3) -- (n5) -- (n7) -- (n9) -- (n1);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result is the same as before.

@licheng, with solution in addendum you now have only one loop ....

Sorry, I made some modifications earlier. Note that in fact, the external yellow vertices are not directly connected by using black edges. If the radius is set to 1.5, problems will occur. Setting the external radius to 1.2 will cover it properly. The image currently displayed in my document is my goal, including its labels.

@licheng, given solution is not hard to adopt to you your new desired design. Special solution in addendum is handy to this. I'm sure that this you can made required changes yourself. Actually, your changes in question is new question ...

Yes, we just need to replace the last line of code with
\draw[thick] (n1) -- (n2) -- (n3) -- (n4) -- (n5) -- (n6) -- (n7) -- (n8) -- (n9) -- (n0) -- (n1);

@licheng, see my second answer. Seem that it provide what you are after

After your editing of question you actually ask ne question hence here is new answer. It based on solution in addendum to the first one:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\node[C=blue!30] (u0)   {$u$};


\foreach  \i  in {0, 1, ..., 9}
{\ifodd\i
    \node[C=orange] (n\i) at (54-\i*36:1.2) {$v_\i$};  
    \draw[red] (u0) -- (n\i);
 \else
    \node[C=white] (n\i) at (54-\i*36:0.8) {$v_\i$};
    \draw   (u0) -- (n\i);
 \fi
}
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\draw[blue]    (n0) -- (n2) -- (n4) -- (n6) -- (n8) -- (n0);
\draw[thick]   (n0) -- (n1) -- (n2) -- (n3) -- (n4) -- (n5) 
                    -- (n6) -- (n7) -- (n8) -- (n9) -- (n0);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Fine tuning for nodes positions I left to you.
